# AWS CodeDeploy is failing on EC2 instances everytime

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

[image]

i have configured a cicd pipeline on aws using jenkins. I have written a very small application that only serves a static index.html file.It is working all the way but breaking at the very last step of codedeploy.
the problem is , when i am trigerring codedeploy from jenkins using aws codedeploy project, it is failing the deployment on the ec2 instances.
Jenkins log is not throwing enough information to debug it. 
Some points that i should make aware of -

1. i am using deployment configuration deployment one at a time instances
2. i havenot installed aws codedeploy agent on the ec2 instances
3. where can i get detailed log on where it is failing? cloudwatch is not logging the codedeploy log in this case.

Error logs-

```
HttpMethod: GET
URL: https://aws-devops-jenkins-docker.s3.amazonaws.com/aws_docker_codebuild_jenkins
Sending request to url: https://aws-devops-jenkins-docker.s3.amazonaws.com/aws_docker_codebuild_jenkins
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Success code from [100‥399]
Saving response body to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/aws_docker_demo/aws-codebuild-artifact.zip
Zipping files into /tmp/#61-6687599754523764921.zip
Uploading zip to s3://aws-devops-jenkins-docker/#61-6687599754523764921.zip
Registering revision for application 'aws_docker_codedeploy_jenkins'
Creating deployment with revision at {RevisionType: S3,S3Location: {Bucket: aws-devops-jenkins-docker,Key: #61-6687599754523764921.zip,BundleType: zip,ETag: 86c6ace4adeaa41f5206ca96c6ff6637},}
Monitoring deployment with ID d-V1R54BRY1...
Deployment status: Created; instances: null
Deployment status: Created; instances: null
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 2,InProgress: 0,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 2,InProgress: 0,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 2,InProgress: 0,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 2,InProgress: 0,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: InProgress; instances: {Pending: 1,InProgress: 1,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 0,Skipped: 0,Ready: 0}
Deployment status: Failed; instances: {Pending: 0,InProgress: 0,Succeeded: 0,Failed: 1,Skipped: 1,Ready: 0}
Deployment did not succeed. Final status: Failed
ERROR: Step ‘Deploy an application to AWS CodeDeploy’ failed: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - echo "installing nodejs"
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - printenv
      - echo "we are in the pre build phase"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "we are in the build block"
      - echo "running test ...."
      - grep -Fq "cloud" index.html
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "we are in the post build phase"

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  name: aws_devops_poc_mywebb_artifacts
```

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /index.html
    destination: /var/www/html/ 
Hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

  ValidateService:
    - location: scripts/validate_service.sh
      timeout: 300
```

**stop_server** and **start_server** scripts are only to start stop httpd service.

**validate_service** script only checks if the html contains the 'world' word.

**install_dependencies** script only install httpd service

I am very new to aws devops. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use buildspec.yaml file? if yes, please share it as well

Comment: @AmitBaranes yes i use. I have added them in  the question above. Please check once.